# Easy way to receive data from Python child thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, exception

I am working on a simple python script that sends serial communication command to an *Arduino*.
I have a *main-thread* which sends the commands and then another *child-thread* which waits for user input.

This should be simple but I want this process to be very fast.
For example if user inputs "stop", I want to stop the main thread *immediately*.

The way I was thinking of doing it was by throwing *exceptions* from the child thread and catch those in the main thread, but I soon realized that I was quite impossible since each thread runs on its own context and child thread can not send an exception to the main thread.

I am now trying to change the child class with attributes and check the attributes in the main thread but I will result on lots of confusing `if-statements` in the main thread and it is also not a good solution since it does not stop the execution immediately.

```
class User_input_thread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.isPauseRequested = False
        self.isStopRequested = False
    def run(self):
        while (True):
            s = raw_input(">")
            if s.startswith("pause"):
                self.isPauseRequested = True
            elif s.startswith("start"):
                self.isPauseRequested = False
            elif s.startswith("stop"):
                self.isStopRequested = True
```

This is the basically main thread:

```
def start_demo():
    user_input_thread = User_input_thread()  
    user_input_thread.start()


    while (True):
        if (not user_input_thread.isPauseRequested):
            # DO SOME WORK HERE
            time.sleep(10)
        if (not user_input_thread.isStopRequested):
            # DO SOME WORK HERE
            time.sleep(10)
```

What is an easy way to achieve the behavior I want?

Please don't link to other pages that discuss exceptions between Threads. At least explain how I should use the code or modify my code so I can understand.

***EDIT*** (following code has been tested)
The problem with the following code is that if event takes infinite time there is no way to stop the child process.
Run the example and write "start".... then the child starts to work and then if you send another event "such as stop" it will be ignored.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import threading
import time

class child_thread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stop_request = threading.Event()
        self.start_request = threading.Event()
        self.pause_request = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            if self.stop_request.isSet():
                print 'stop request is set!!'
                self.stop_request.clear()
                while 1:
                    print "stop running..."
                    time.sleep(1)
            if self.pause_request.isSet():
                print 'pause request is set!!'
                self.pause_request.clear()
                while 1:
                    print "pause running..."
                    time.sleep(1)
            if self.start_request.isSet():
                print 'start request is set!!!'
                self.start_request.clear()
                while 1:
                    print "start running..."
                    time.sleep(1)

    def show(self, event='stop'):
        if event == 'stop':
            self.stop_request.set()
        elif event == 'start':
            self.start_request.set()
        elif event == 'pause':
            self.pause_request.set()
        elif event == 'exit':
            print 'enter exit'
            self.join(1)


def main_thread():

    t1 = child_thread()
    t1.start()

    while 1:
        s = raw_input(">")
        t1.show(event=s)
        if s == 'exit':
            break

    print 'Done! child thread has been killed'

main_thread()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a best practice to for a `child thread` to control its `parent thread`. We usually do the other way around.

In your case, you can put user input in the main thread and put your work in the child thread.
 Communication between threads in Python is usually done by Event and signal. You can google this if you show interests.

Here is an example for your case. Hope it helps. I simplify the if conditions which is not the key point here. :)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import threading
import time


class child_thread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stop_request = threading.Event()
        self.start_request = threading.Event()
        self.pause_request = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            if self.stop_request.isSet():
                print 'stop request is set!!'
                break
            if self.pause_request.isSet():
                print 'pause request is set!!'
                break
            if self.start_request.isSet():
                print 'start request is set!!!'
                break
            print 'no stop/pause/start is set!!'
            time.sleep(1)

    def join(self, timeout=None, event='stop'):
        if event == 'stop':
            self.stop_request.set()
        elif event == 'start':
            self.start_request.set()
        elif event == 'pause':
            self.pause_request.set()

        super(child_thread, self).join(timeout)

def main_thread():

    t1 = child_thread()
    t1.start()

    while 1:
        s = raw_input(">")
        t1.join(event=s)
        break
    print 'Done! chile thread has been killed'

main_thread()
```

And here is a very good article for communications between threads in Python. http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/27/python-threads-communication-and-stopping

EDIT:

Here is code for your updated request.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import threading
import time


class child_thread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stop_request = threading.Event()
        self.start_request = threading.Event()
        self.pause_request = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            if self.stop_request.isSet():
                print 'stop request is set!!'
                self.stop_request.clear()
                continue
            if self.pause_request.isSet():
                print 'pause request is set!!'
                self.pause_request.clear()
                continue
            if self.start_request.isSet():
                print 'start request is set!!!'
                self.start_request.clear()
                continue

    def show(self, event='stop'):
        if event == 'stop':
            self.stop_request.set()
        elif event == 'start':
            self.start_request.set()
        elif event == 'pause':
            self.pause_request.set()
        elif event == 'exit':
            print 'enter exit'
            self.join(1)


def main_thread():

    t1 = child_thread()
    t1.start()

    while 1:
        s = raw_input("\n>enter exit to exit:")
        t1.show(event=s)
        if s == 'exit':
            break

    print 'Done! chile thread has been killed'

main_thread()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a question, will calling join() from main_thread have immediate effect on the child_thread? and also is there a way more than one Event. For example one for stop, one for start, one for pause and so on?

Comment: @theAlse Yes, it will take effect immediately. Check my update for several events.

Comment: Hi, I tried this code and thanks, but main_thread has only one chance to call child_thread. Then main_thread waits for child_thread to terminate but I want child_thread to run continuously start/stop/pause until a new command is received and then execute that command until a new command is received and so on.

Comment: hi and thank you for the reply, I tested your code, please see edited question and you will see what the problem is.

Comment: @theAlse Of course it will keep printing since there is no break or event.clear() in your code.